# Spring Boot 2, Spring 5 JPA: Dealing with multiple OneToMany JoinTables

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Not sure the best approach to implementing the CrudRepository for an Entity that has multiple
@OneToMany associations with a @JoinTable

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contact", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames ={"first_name","last_name"})})
@SuppressWarnings("PersistenceUnitPresent")
public class Contact extends Auditable implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "contact_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "contact_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "contact_generator", sequenceName = "contact_seq", allocationSize = 50)
    private Long contactId;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name = "middle_name", nullable = true)
    private String middleName;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( 
        name = "contact_phone"
    )
    private List<Phone> phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "contact_email")
    private List<EmailAddress> emailAddresses = new ArrayList<>();
```

```
public interface ContactRepo  extends CrudRepository<Contact, Long> {
    
    List<Contact> findByLastNameContainingIgnoreCase(String lastName);

}
```

I have the FetchType.LAZY so I don't get the MultipleBagFetchException from 2 cartesian products.
So I know I need to split the 2 joins up which is where I am stuck as to the best solution.
Put in a custom repo and customImpl class that has can access the EntityManager and code out the 2 joins?
I am not crazy and letting Java take care of the cartesian via a Set, nor the one having FetchType.EAGER and dealing with the other with another query??

Generates:

```
    create table contact (
       contact_id bigint not null,
        create_tm timestamp not null,
        created_by varchar(255) not null,
        updated_tm timestamp not null,
        updated_by varchar(255) not null,
        first_name varchar(255) not null,
        last_name varchar(255) not null,
        middle_name varchar(255),
        primary key (contact_id)
    )
    create table email_address (
       email_id bigint not null,
        email_addr varchar(255) not null,
        email_type varchar(255),
        primary_addr boolean default false,
        primary key (email_id)
    )

    create table contact_email (
       Contact_contact_id bigint not null,
        emailAddresses_email_id bigint not null
    )

    create table phone (
       phone_id bigint not null,
        phone_nbr varchar(255) not null,
        phone_type varchar(255),
        primary_ph boolean default false,
        primary key (phone_id)
    )

    create table contact_phone (
       Contact_contact_id bigint not null,
        phoneNumbers_phone_id bigint not null
    )
```

The strange think is my JpaDataTests worked find. The find all and findByLastNameContainingIgnoreCase return the phone numbers and email addresses.

However, The Service does not.

```
    @Autowired
    private ContactRepo contactRepo;
    
    @Override
    public List<Contact> findAllContacts() throws GcaServiceException {
        try {
            Iterable<Contact> iter = contactRepo.findAll();
            return IteratorUtils.toList(iter.iterator());
        } catch(DataAccessException e) {
            throw new GcaServiceException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public List<Contact> findByLastName(String lastName) throws GcaServiceException {
        try {
            return contactRepo.findByLastNameContainingIgnoreCase(lastName);
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            throw new GcaServiceException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

```
[
      {
      "createTm": "2021-01-11T16:27:19.995011",
      "createdBy": "UncleMoose",
      "updatedBy": "UncleMoose",
      "updateTm": "2021-01-11T16:27:19.995011",
      "contactId": 1,
      "firstName": "Bruce",
      "lastName": "Randall",
      "middleName": null,
      "phoneNumbers": [],
      "emailAddresses": []
   },
      {
      "createTm": "2021-01-11T16:27:19.996009",
      "createdBy": "UncleMoose",
      "updatedBy": "UncleMoose",
      "updateTm": "2021-01-11T16:27:19.996009",
      "contactId": 51,
      "firstName": "Boss",
      "lastName": "Randall",
      "middleName": null,
      "phoneNumbers": [],
      "emailAddresses": []
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the mystery of DataJpaTest vs manual integration testing differences was I decided to look at a map and make sure I wasn't hiking down the wrong Google trail. I turned the H2 console on and found the Join Tables empty even though the insert occurred? However, I notice I was getting different Join Table column names between live and automated testing.

Solution was to explicitly name the Join Table columns. It appears Spring has handled the MultipleBagFetchException issues with multiple OneToMany JoinTable attributes in an Entity.

```
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( 
        name = "contact_phone"
       ,joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id")
       ,inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "phone_id")
    )
    private List<Phone> phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "contact_email"
       ,joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id")
       ,inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "email_id")
    )
    private List<EmailAddress> emailAddresses = new ArrayList<>();
```